# Item_Load Event: Outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection is not null but cannot be casted to Selection (throws Exception) why?

Tags: outlook-addin

I try to develop an Outlook addin. I registered on the Item_Load event with this code:

```
Application.ItemLoad += Item_Load;
```

In the event handler I use this code:

```
 [...]
 Outlook.Explorer explorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
                        if (explorer != null)
                        {
                            if (explorer.Selection == null)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                            int count = explorer.Selection.Count;
                            if (count > 0)
                            {
                                Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection[1];
```

This throws an Exception as the explorer.Select[1] does not deliver an Outlook.Selection? How is this possible as Outlook.Explorer.Selection[] is defined as:https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection so it should deliver a Selection?

Answer (score 0):

The `Selection` property returns a [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection) object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window. So the code should like this:

```
Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;
```

But if you use an indexer you get an instance of Outlook items:

```
Outlook.MailItem mail = explorer.Selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
```

Remember that the `ItemLoad` event provides an instance of the loaded Outlook item as a parameter to the event handler. So, there is no need to get the currently selected items.